# How most iOS developers adapt different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder how other ios developers adapt application for supporting all different screen sizes. I personally used in every single view UIDevice API and Outlets for constraint. 
But as time goes by, I became doubtful. Is it the way it is supposed to be? 
What is the most efficient way to adjust my application for supporting all different screen sizes?

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
  constraint1.constant = value
  constraint2.constant = value
  constraint3.constant = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI already adapts to different screen sizes if you're using auto layout constraints. I think your question is more about how to have different layouts for different screen sizes.

The problem with your approach is that your app may be used as multitasking in split view which means that your if statement is already predicting it wrong. Why? You see your app can be used in one of the layouts shown below.

[image]

But your are checking if your device is iPad which doesn't tell you much about what kind of layout your app is in.

**Size classes here to rescue**

> Size classes are traits that are automatically assigned to content areas based on their size. The system defines two size classes, regular (denotes expansive space) and compact (denotes constrained space), which describe the height and width of a view.

More sophisticated solution will be to use *size classes* which gives you more options on how to arrange your views. So now you should go from this

```swift
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
  constraint1.constant = value
  constraint2.constant = value
  constraint3.constant = value
}
```

to this

```swift
if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact && traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

I hope I'd give you a general idea of how to start using size classes now is up to you to do further research. You can start in apple documentation with [UITraitCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection) class.

Resource: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/